# Maintain State Between HTTP Requests to Keycloak in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, keycloak

So I am trying to automate a JMeter script that creates Keycloak users and then signs them in.

First It GETs the login page and stores the code, here is an example request:

```
GET http://Keycloak.com:8001//auth/realms/REALM/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT&scope=openid%20profile%20email&nonce=N5b3a2da23c04a&response_mode=form_post&resource=RESOURCE&state=2SJwtlVZrswlGkw&redirect_uri=REDIRECTURI
```

However, when I then GET the registration page, the code changes and the tab_id also changes. How can I keep keycloak from generating a new code token with every HTTP request in a thread?

In addition, why is each HTTP request with JMeter acting like a new session instead of the next request in a series?

---

**EDIT:**

I am using Regular Expression Extractors in order to track the code and execution variables, in addition to using a HTTP Cookie Manager and HTTP Cache Manager for the thread.

Looking at my POST request, both variables are the same as those from the previous HTTP request, and all of my cookies are being maintained, yet every time I try this automated login, I get a 400 error and the keycloak event log displays an invalid_code error.

---

**Edit:**
As requested here is a screenshot of all my sign in requests
[image]

Comment: Can you show the structureof your test plan ? Thanks

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK as In what Order My HTTP Request scome in?

Comment: somewhat, we need to know the structure of your plan to understand

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK  I need to load the moodle page to get my moodle session key, then from there load my keycloak login to get my keycloak code and state, then push the username and password to the keycloak login. This requires the session and code, but using the ones I get from my pull results in the error invalid_code in my log

Comment: thanks, but can you click on + button and put the screenshot here. thanks

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably your Regular Expression Extractor is not nested in the HTTP Request you are trying to extract data from.

If its scope is too wide, it applies to all HTTP Requests, so first time it succeeds extracting, but then for the next request that does not contain the token, the extractor runs and overwrites the old value by an empty one.

See scoping rules in JMeter:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules

Comment: It is nested in the HTTP request, The issue is that Keycloak generates a new code for the POST request, even though it shouldn't

Comment: Does it mean you need to update it ? Could you show a screenshot of your plan fully expanded ? Thnaks

Comment: No, Looking at the requests from the browser, keycloak should NOT generate a new key.

Comment: Try setting in Cookie Manager the policy to Standard if using JMeter >= 3.0. And by the way use jmeter 4.0

Answer (score 2):

You need to maintain the corelation between hits. Please go through below blog

> https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter

Comment: The issue is that I am using a Regular Expression Extractor to get the code value. It is just that the next Request causes this value to change
And running in BlazeMeter Doesn't seem to help at all

Comment: In addition, the listener that BlazeMeter uses to create a JMeter script also fails to maintain corelation in its script

Comment: Please provide the more details how you are maintaining the coreleation and what errors you are facing.

Comment: I am using Regular Expression Extractors in order to track the code and execution variables, in addition to using a HTTP Cookie Manager and HTTP Cache Manager for the thread.

Looking at my POST request, both variables are the same as those from the previous HTTP request, and all of my cookies are being maintained, yet every time I try this automated login, I get a 400 error and the keycloak event log displays an invalid_code error.

Answer (score 0):

According to [keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/server_installation/topics/network/https.html) you must use **https** if you are using `keycloak.com`

> Keycloak can run out of the box without SSL so long as you stick to private IP addresses like localhost, 127.0.0.1, 10.0.x.x, 192.168.x.x, and 172..16.x.x. If you don’t have SSL/HTTPS configured on the server or you try to access Keycloak over HTTP from a non-private IP adress you will get an error.

So you have 3 options: use private IP address, use a reverse proxy or load balancer to handle HTTPS or enable HTTPS for the Keycloak server.